# Model records in OctoberCMS Static Pages

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

I can't seem to find any documentation for this or think straight, how can get my plugin records populated in the static page content area. So what I am looking for is, something like a record finder field where I can connect, say Users Plugin, and then select the User through the record finder.

Please guide me to a starting point or documentation I may have missed.

Answer (score 0):

**Snippets**

Go to https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-pages -> click Documentation -> scroll down about 85% ~ 90% down. There you will find the information you are looking for.

[image]